# Submitting form is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a webpage that creates a form with a number of select tags dynamically by means of some javascript/jquery code. When submitting the form a php file (form_submit.php) must process the submitted form fields. Furthermore I use Netbeans 7.4 for php debugging.

My problem: when I select some values in the form and submit the form the debugger shows empty submitted values (e.g., default values "NOSELECTION" for no selection) within form_submit.php instead of the selected values. The console within the submit function in the code below does show the selected submitted values (and therefore also confirms that the built html form with the select tags is correct).

I do not assume this a is a bug in Netbeans, so where do I go wrong? I suspect there is a bug in the jquery submit function below, but I cant's see it...

Javascript code:

```
//main function document ready    
$(document).ready(function(){

//only part of code here to build the form with a number of <select>'s
ecorp_eproductoptions = '<select  id="selected_eproductid'+ff+'" class="eprodtype" name="selected_eproductid'+ff+'">';
ff++;
ecorp_eproductoptions += '<option selected="selected" value="NOSELECTION" > Koppel uw product </option>';

for(var k=0; k< Staticvars.ecorp_nrofeproducts;k++){
  ecorp_eproductoptions += '<option value="'+ Staticvars.suppliername[i] +'_'+Staticvars.agreementid[i] +'_'+ supplier_eproductid +'_'+ Staticvars.ecorp_eproductid[k] +'"> '+ Staticvars.ecorp_eproductname[k] +' </option>';
  }//for var k
  ecorp_eproductoptions += '</select>';
  form += '<td> '+ ecorp_eproductoptions +' </td></tr>';
//etc...

//FUNCTION Submit()
$("#myForm").submit(function(){

    console.log('SUBMITTED FORM: '+ $( this ).serialize() ); //shows values for select tags!

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form_submit.php",
        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(msg){
        if(msg.statusgeneral == 'success'){

        }
        else
        {

        }//else
        }, //succes: function   
        error: function(){

    $("#errorbox").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
        }
    });//.ajax

//make sure the form doesn't post
return false;


});//$("#myForm").submit()

}); //$(document).ready
```

HTML code:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">    
    <div id="wrapper"></div> <!--anchor point for adding set of product form fields -->   
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Bevestig">
</form>
```

Comment: note that in the browser's console you display the value returned by `$( this ).serialize()`, but you post `$("#myForm").serialize()`. Maybe this is the reason.

Comment: thx for you comment; Do you suggest I post wrongly? What should be the correct post then?

Comment: I would try to post `$( this ).serialize()` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I think the problem is in your form_submit.php, are you checking the values of selected_eproductid+ff

Comment: @akonsu: just tried $( this ).serialize(); no difference

Comment: @Michael Aguilar: apart from a 'session_start()' there is actually nothing in the php code yet; I'm just watching the $_POST varaiables with the Netbeans debugger; the debugger shows $_POST[selected_eproductid0], $_POST[selected_eproductid1] variables but with the standard 'NOSELECTION' values instead of the selected values

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to jQuery too, but I think the problem is the fact that your `$.ajax` call is running asynchronously which allows the submit event handler to continue on and return false before your form sends the values...just a newbie guess. :)

Have you tried adding `async: false` to your `$.ajax` call?

Comment: but he use `return false;`

Comment: My understanding was that `return false` was to prevent the form element from performing its default action of submitting.  The `async` property determines whether the function continues while the AJAX request is in progress...right?

Comment: @thankyour: I tried the async:false suggestion; then the form stops working (so I can't enter form input).

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why happens that, but please try this

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
var dataAjax = $( this ).serialize();
console.log('SUBMITTED FORM: '+ dataAjax  ); //shows values for select tags!

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "form_submit.php",
    data: dataAjax,
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(msg){
    if(msg.statusgeneral == 'success'){

    }
    else
    {

    }//else
    }, //succes: function   
    error: function(){

$("#errorbox").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
    }
});//.ajax
//make sure the form doesn't post
return false;
});//$("#myForm").submit()
```

Comment: console output: SUBMITTED FORM: agreementapproval0=SolarX_10&selected_emeterproductid0=SolarX_10_1_1&selected_eproductid0=SolarX_10_2_4&selected_emeterproductid1=NOSELECTION&selected_emeterproductid2=NOSELECTION&selected_eproductid1=NOSELECTION&selected_eproductid2=NOSELECTION&form_token=0cdd3d4b77bf1d5b16c51c0bd094162a

Comment: the first parameter 'agreementapproval0' actually does show a value in the debugger (but that is not select type).

Comment: maybe you are watching previous values, are you refreshing the values in your netbeans?

Comment: How do you refresh values in netbeans? I start a new debugger session after each code change and assume that the values are then refreshed automatically(?)

Comment: ps: I added another <select> just to test (form += '<select id="TESTSELECT'+ww+'" name="TESTSELECT'+ww+'"> <option selected="selected" value="NOSELECTEDTESTVALUE"></option> <option value="selectedtestval'+ww+'"></option> ';) - with the same effect: select value is displayed in console but not in debugger